# How do I omit a WP category from this function?

Tags: php, wordpress

The category tag ID is "4". I'd like to get rid of the date from these posts. Here is the code that adds the date after all posts:

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && is_main_query()) {
    $content .= '<p class="my-date-style"> '.get_the_date ('F j, Y'). '&nbsp;'.'| by Alexander Gilmour </p>';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```